# Eclipse bundle dependency resolving

Tags: dependencies, osgi, bundle, manifest, pde

I am currently trying to compile my Eclipse PDE projects. To do this
i have to collect all the dependencies from the Require-Bundle
instructions found in the projects and its dependencies. Now i have
come across a problem that one of my projects fails if i want to compile it
as it references the class `org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point` from the
`org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86` bundle. The problem seems to be
that the dependency to `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86` could not
be resolved.

Using the dependency view of eclipse i can see that `org.eclipse.ui`
depends on `org.eclipse.swt` and `org.eclipse.swt` depends on `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86`.

**Here's my question:**

I don't understand how eclipse knows that
`org.eclipse.swt` depends on `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86`. The
manifest file of `org.eclipse.swt` does not have a Require-Bundle
(or other information related to the bundle
`org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86`) statement. So how does it know??

Thanks for you help,

Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's kind of an inverted dependency, because `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86` is a fragment bundle that is hosted by the base `org.eclipse.swt` bundle and extends its API. The SWT base bundle is unusual because it contains no code at all... everything is in the platform-specific fragments.

This works in PDE because the base bundle contains the header "Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true". When PDE sees this header, it searches for fragments that can add API to the base bundle. Sadly if you are writing some kind of build process to automate PDE builds you will need to replicate the same logic.

Fortunately, at build time you don't need to worry about which platform you are compiling for: the signatures of all the classes and methods are the same across the supported platforms, so you can easily compile using the Win32 fragment even if you are compiling on a Mac (for example).